# How to destroy the gridrotator() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [jQuery gridrotator effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/) for my photo gallery. This plugin creates a grid of images inside a number of columns and rows which will arrange the images into the grid and the remaining images will appear with different animations and delays. But to do this the tag `<img>` is removed and is replaced by anchor `<a>` with src into the style.

from this:

```
<img src="thumbnail/23.jpg"/>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#" style="background-image: url(thumbnail/23.jpg);">
```

I want to disable that rotator effect and keep static images by clicking on a button. So I tried to add the `<img>` tag and remove anchor tag:

```
$("#destroy").click(function(){
    $("#ri-grid").attr('id','ri-order');
    var anchor = $("#ri-order").children('ul').find('a');
    anchor.each( function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        $(this).parent().append('<img />');
        $(this).parent().find('img').attr( 'src' , bg );

        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Here is the [**example**](http://domandar.com/test/index.html). If you click on "Disable Effect" button you can see that my code works fine but after a few seconds the tag anchor and the animation returns in the DOM.

Why? Is there a way to disable that effect? or how can I disable or destroy the `gridrotator()` function?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Grid = $("#ri-grid").clone();
$("#ri-grid").html("").replaceWith(Grid);
$(".ri-grid").attr("id", "ri-grid-new");
```

Add this to the beginning of your `$("#destroy").click` function and that should do the trick.

Comment: In testing it looks like you can replace your entire `$("#destroy").click` function with just these 3 lines here for a simple kill shot. Will need to be altered if you want to reinitialize it, didn't go there tho.

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, there is another issue, in the html I have 40 images and when I click on destroy button I see only 25 (`$("ul.files").find("li").length;`). Can I also display the hidden ones?

Comment: Hmm, does it shrink from a 40 block grid to 25 block grid? I setup a test @ jsfiddle last night didn't notice this behavior, looked like everything froze up properly when destroy was ran.